# Is a namedtuple the way to go for a flexible container?

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

I am quite new to Python and I don't know what is available. Currently, I have this piece of code to quickly put some named variables together, so I can use them in other places:

```
def myfunction():
    props = namedtuple('props', '')

    props.color = "green"
    props.size = "large"
    props.wheels = 4
    props.roof = True

    return props
```

Is in this case the `namedtuple` a good solution? Or can it be simpler?

Comment: You are actually using `namedtuple` incorrectly. `props` is a *class*.

Comment: Actually tuples are quite _inflexible_ containers, at least the individual ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`namedtuple` is *excellent* tool to produce fixed-sized pieces of (immutable) information, just like tuples but with named attributes for convenience.

However, you are using the `namedtuple` class factory incorrectly. `props` is a *class*, you normally would use it like this:

```
Props = namedtuple('Props', 'color size wheels roof')

def myfunction():
    props = Props(color="green", size="large", wheels=4, roof=True)
    return props
```

This makes `props` immutable (the end-user can generate a new instance by using the [`namedtuple._replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace)), and indexable as well.

The only reason you didn't run into issues with your approach is that you create a new class object each time your function runs; the class attributes you set on it are not shared between instances because no instances are ever created.

If you didn't want an immutable object, use a dictionary instead:

```
def myfunction():
    return {
        "color": "green",
        "size": "large",
        "wheels": 4,
        "roof": True
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using `props` to store data, the simplest option would be to use a `dict`:

```
def myfunction():
    return {"color": "green",
            "size": "large",
            "wheels": 4,
            "roof": True}
```

Elements of the `dict` are then accessed as `props["color"]` and so forth (once you've stored the return value in a variable named "props", of course).